# How to save variables in Variable Explorer of Spyder IDE

Tags: python, pandas, automation, export-to-csv, spyder

I am using Spyder IDE. I want to save the variables in the Variable Explorer of Spyder to a csv/excel/pdf. I am automating a task. Hence I want to save the results every time I run the script. My variable explorer looks like this:

[image]

Or is there a way I can write all the variables to a csv or pdf?

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the most efficient way but what about:

```
import pandas as pd
import time
```

you save every variable as a dataframe, but to do it with float/int values you have to create dataframe like:

```
b = 4
x = pd.DataFrame({"col" : [b]})
```

use time to mark time of file creation

```
t = time.localtime()
timestamp = time.strftime('%b-%d-%Y_%H%M', t)

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path + '\\results_EC_' + timestamp  + ".xlsx")
```

at this point select all dataframes, which you want to export:

```
x.to_excel(writer,sheet_name="Results1", index = False)

writer.save()
print("done")
```

Comment: what packages will I have to install for this

Comment: pandas and time should be enough. In case you get an error you can also find out, which package is missing in the console and eventually add it as well.